# how to run class java use runtime.exec()?

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

I must run a class java by another program java use runtime.exec().
A class in folder diffefent with my program so i cannot run it.
I used (java -cp "directory" class) but a my class has import file so it cannot filenotfound?
Who can help me?

Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp \"E:\DA_Laptrinhmang\" NguyenTo");

Here is program:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
public class TestCodeJava {
  private static void printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(ins));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(name + " " + line);
    }
  }
  private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
    Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));
    pro.waitFor();
    String line = "";
    while((line = reader.readLine())!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
  }
  private static int toCompile(String fileToCompile)
  {
      JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
      int compilationResult = compiler.run(null,  null, null, "-verbose", fileToCompile);
      return compilationResult;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      if(toCompile("E:\\Folder\\Prime.java")==0)
      {
         runProcess("java -cp \"E:\\Folder\" Prime");
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

    import java.io.*;
    public class Prime {
    private static boolean isPrime(int n)
    {
        if(n <= 1) return false;
        if(n == 2 || n == 3) return true;
        int m = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
        for(int i = 5; i <= m; i = i + 5)
            if(n % i == 0 || n % (i+2) == 0) return false;
        return true;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        File file = new File("INPUT.TXT");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        File file2 = new File("OUTPUT.TXT");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file2);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
        if(isPrime(n))
        {
            writer.write("YES");
        }else writer.write("NO");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

here is error:
[parsing started RegularFileObject[E:\DA_Laptrinhmang\NguyenTo.java]]
[parsing completed 42ms]
[search path for source files: C:\Users\QUANG HUY\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ChamDiemJava\build\classes,C:\Users\QUANG HUY\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ChamDiemJava\src]
[search path for class files: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\resources.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\rt.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\jsse.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\jce.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\charsets.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\classes,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar,C:\Users\QUANG HUY\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ChamDiemJava\build\classes,C:\Users\QUANG HUY\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ChamDiemJava\src]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Object.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/String.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/FileNotFoundException.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/IOException.class)]]
[checking NguyenTo]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/AutoCloseable.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Math.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Exception.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Throwable.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/File.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/net/URI.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/FileInputStream.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/FileDescriptor.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/BufferedReader.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/InputStreamReader.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/InputStream.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/Reader.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Integer.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Number.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/FileOutputStream.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/BufferedWriter.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/OutputStream.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/Writer.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Error.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/RuntimeException.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/NumberFormatException.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.class)]]
[wrote RegularFileObject[E:\DA_Laptrinhmang\NguyenTo.class]]
[total 441ms]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: And what errors are you getting?  Why isn't it working?  Have you tried running it from the command line from the same context as you application would be...?

Comment: I try run code java in E disk by cmd, but i can't because my class has import file. I need exect code java by another programe with runtime.exect().

Comment: I see what appears to be a part of a classpath (improperly escaped) but no main class or jar file.

Comment: Can you use a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)? That makes escaping the commandline a lot less tedious (e.g. `"E:\\DA_Laptrinhmang NguyenTo"`)

Comment: Alright, that statement made no sense. If you can't execute the class from the command line, what makes you think you'll be able to do it from your program?

Comment: when i run TestCodeJava by netbean to run code Prime by runtime.exec then Prime.java cannot found file INPUT.TXT, but when i run Prima.java by netbean then it can found.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RunSomeJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp E:\\workspaceIndigo2\\StackOverflow\\bin mypackage.SomeOtherProgram");
    }

}
```

and

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SomeOtherProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f = new File(System.currentTimeMillis()+".txt");
        f.createNewFile();
    }

}
```

Comment: you've modified the question, it's another question

Comment: this was not nice, mr @Student

Comment: No, i sorry, but i try description my question